# React-Native automatically scroll down

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I have an app with one ScrollView and a button and a long text inside inside:

```
return (
    <ScrollView>
        <Button onPress={slowlyScrollDown} title="Slowly scroll a bit down..." />
        <Text>
              [ Very long text here where user has to scroll ]
        </Text>
    </ScrollView>
)
```

When the user presses the button, I want to slowly scroll down a bit, like that he can see like
the first 5-10 lines of the Text.

I would accept any answer that provides a piece of code how I can implement that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am not sure it will work but that is the direction:

```
const [offset,setOffset] = useState(0);
const scrollViewRef = useRef();

const slowlyScrollDown = () => {
    const y = offset + 80;
    scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({x: 0, y, animated: true});
    setOffset(y);
}

return (
    <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} >
        <Button onPress={slowlyScrollDown} title="Slowly scroll a bit down..." />
        <Text>
              [ Very long text here where user has to scroll ]
        </Text>
    </ScrollView>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `scrollTo()` to scroll to a given x, y offset, either immediately, with a smooth animation.

For that take a reference of the scroll view using `useRef`. then follow the below `autoScroll()` method to implement the programmatic scroll in your application.

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import {  ScrollView, Text, Button  } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

    const scrollViewRef = useRef();

    const autoScroll = () => {
        let offset = 0;
        setInterval(()=> {
            offset += 20
            scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo({x: 0, y: offset, animated: true})
        }, 1000)
    }

    return (
        <ScrollView ref={scrollViewRef} >
            <Button onPress={autoScroll} title="Start scrolling" />
            <Text>
                [ long text ]
            </Text>
        </ScrollView>
    )
}
```